wp-admin dashboad not open, page not found error comes each time
i accidently change permalinks setting from the WordPress dashboard now my wp-admin panel not open i try all method like recreate new .htaccess file or changing the name of plugins folder or theme folder but my problem is does not solve what should i do now? and i also delete my WordPress website and its database many times but error does not solve. and whenever i try to login wp-admin a deleteme.soo url is add automatically with the side url please help me im in very trouble.my main domain wordpress website files in public_html and my second domain wordpress website file is like public_html/secondwebsite/files
i want to open my WordPress dashboard in any condition. but all time page not found error comes to me
